# Decode UUID 4 as a Python string

Tags: python, encoding, uuid, utf-16, utf

I would like to generate a UUID v4 string starting from the `uuid` import from the Python standard library.

I know I can cast a UUID to `str` by doing `str(uuid.uuid4())`, however I am trying to understand what the bytes in that class instance mean. While trying to decode those bytes I see all sorts of errors, either the string is not the one I expect, or an exception is thrown. I think these bytes are UTF-16 encoded as per documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.bytes

> UUID instances have these read-only attributes:
>
> UUID.bytes
> The UUID as a 16-byte string (containing the six integer fields in big-endian byte order).

However what I get from those fields is not the expected UUID I get when casting to `str`, why is this happening?

```
>>> import uuid
>>> my_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
>>> str(my_uuid)
'3f5017be-a314-4bb2-92c0-5135b47f8c45'
>>> my_uuid.bytes.decode('latin1')
'?P\x17¾£\x14K²\x92ÀQ5´\x7f\x8cE'
>>> my_uuid.bytes.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
'?P\x17\x14KQ5\x7fE'
>>> my_uuid.bytes.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 3: invalid start byte
>>> my_uuid.bytes.decode('utf-16')
'倿븗ᒣ뉋삒㕑羴䖌'
>>> my_uuid.bytes_le.decode('utf-16')
'ើ㽐ꌔ䮲삒㕑羴䖌'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding bytes is for *text* not structures so do not try to decode them.  To inspect the bytes, use `.hex()`:

```py
import uuid
u = uuid.uuid4()
print(u)
print(u.bytes.hex(' '))
print([hex(n) for n in u.fields])
```

Output:

```
6ea36117-e3d1-464a-94ee-1571104650a5
6e a3 61 17 e3 d1 46 4a 94 ee 15 71 10 46 50 a5
['0x6ea36117', '0xe3d1', '0x464a', '0x94', '0xee', '0x1571104650a5']
```

See [this Raymond Chen "Old New Thing" blog article about GUIDS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220928-00/?p=107221) for more information and why the 6 integer fields are printed as 5.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes don't "mean" anything; they are -- as the description says -- "six integer fields in big-endian byte order". You would not expect them to decode meaningfully into strings.

You can use the `struct` module to unpack the individual values and convert them yourself. For example:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> import struct
>>> my_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
>>> my_uuid
UUID('11a0a5e5-6733-47c3-9a2d-8cd1c7d01e2c')
>>> [hex(i) for i in struct.unpack('>8H', my_uuid.bytes)]
['0x11a0', '0xa5e5', '0x6733', '0x47c3', '0x9a2d', '0x8cd1', '0xc7d0', '0x1e2c']
```

You can see the hex values returned in the above list correspond to the string value of the UUID.

Comment: What's the meaning of "8" in that `>8H` string? How to build that string starting from the information in the docs of UTF-16 big-endian? Also: where are those 6 integer buried? In here the unpack gives back 8 elements - are these related in any way with the 6 integers?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the docs for the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). The `8` means `8 H values`, where `H` means an unsigned short, or 2-byte value.

Comment: I'm actually unsure about the "six integer fields" bit; a UUID is typically represented as 5 fields, as documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format).

Comment: The fourth field is actually two of the "6 integer fields".  See [this Raymond Chen "Old New Thing" article on GUIDs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220928-00/?p=107221)